# How do I start a new test session in OpenTest?

Tags: java, node.js, automated-tests, opentest

I have installed OpenTest and want to start a new session.

How do I do this?

I tried searching for this on Google but only found a PR talking about using the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to start a test session:

1. **From the web-based user interface**. Go to the `Session` / `Create Test Session...` menu option, then select the tests you want to run, fill in other test session properties, as needed, and click the `Create Session` button.
2. **Using a test session template**. This can be done from the UI, or through the web API:

   - From the UI: use the `Session` / `Create Session From Template...`
   - Using the API: fill-in the `template` property of the JSON payload. Mode details [here](https://getopentest.org/reference/web-api.html#creating-a-test-session).
3. **Using the web API** and passing the properties of the test session, as described [here](https://getopentest.org/reference/web-api.html#creating-a-test-session).

Example API call:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/session

{
    "environment": "prod",
    "sessionLabel": "Run smoke tests",
    "tests": [
        {
            "path": ".",
            "name": "Smoke test 1"
        },
        {
            "path": ".",
            "name": "Web test 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using https://getopentest.org/docs/environments.html as a guide, reading into Step 1, I believe that clicking on the plus as noted in the diagram is how once could start a new session.

[image]